# Вычислить функцию через переменную

Tags: функции, асимптотика, псевдокод

Вычислите значение функции через переменную:

```
Pestiferous (n)
       r = 0;
       for i = 1 to n do
           for j = 1 to i do
               for k = j to i + j do
                   for l = 1 to i + j - k do
                           r = r + 1;
       return (r)
```

Я пробывал посчитать через суммы и получил `r = n(n + 1)(n + 2)(n + 3) / 24`, но ответ не прошёл проверку компьютером.

Comment: Сформулируйте вопрос. Сейчас вопроса в вопросе не видно.

Comment: Уточните как работает `for a = b to c do`. Сколько будет итераций?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Я допустил ошибку в вычислениях, если кому интересно вот моё решение [на другом форуме](https://dxdy.ru/post1628878.html#p1628878)

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Вставь формулу картинкой